# htmlunit: Send POST form and retrieve the response

Tags: java, htmlunit

The website: http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/jcrS00Alias
It has 2 frames,

one with the POST form:http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/frameCriterioBusqueda.jsp

and the other frame to show the results: http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/frameResultadoBusqueda.html

Testing in Apache Netbeans sends me an error:

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ htmunit ---
sep 30, 2019 8:39:15 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
ADVERTENCIA: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
sep 30, 2019 8:39:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
ADVERTENCIA: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
sep 30, 2019 8:39:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener scriptException
GRAVE: Error during JavaScript execution
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[0] column=[0] lineSource=[function () {] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[load event for HtmlBody[] in http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/jcrS00Alias] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "goRefresh" of undefined]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "goRefresh" of undefined

My advance:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try {
            String url = "http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/frameCriterioBusqueda.jsp";
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
            webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

            HtmlPage htmlpage = webClient.getPage(url);

            //webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
            //CookieManager coo = webClient.getCookieManager();
            //Cookie cookie = coo.getCookie("TS01c75c6f");
            //System.out.println(cookie.getValue());

            HtmlForm htmlForm = htmlpage.getElementByName("mainForm");
            //htmlForm.setActionAttribute("jcrS00Alias");
            HtmlTextInput input1 = htmlForm.getInputByName("search1");
            HtmlTextInput input2 = htmlForm.getInputByName("codigo");
            input1.setText("10468790497");

            HtmlHiddenInput hidden = (HtmlHiddenInput)htmlForm.getInputByName("accion");
            hidden.setValueAttribute("consPorRuc");

            HtmlImage image = htmlpage.<HtmlImage>getFirstByXPath("//img[@src='captcha?accion=image']");
            ImageReader img = image.getImageReader();
            BufferedImage buf = img.read(0);
            // Show image
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buf);
            String codigo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, icon, "Captcha image", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            input2.setText(codigo);

            HtmlButton boton = (HtmlButton) htmlpage.createElement("button");
            boton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            htmlForm.appendChild(boton);

            htmlpage = boton.click();

            System.out.println(htmlpage.asXml().toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I look forward to returning a successful query.

Comment: Will have a look

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with something general:

For the setup of the client, please set only the options you really need. The default is to behave like a real browser, there is no need to e.g. enable cookies.

There are some warnings you can ignore

> Cannot call method "goRefresh" of undefined

This is because the js in the frame (in your case the result frame document) tries to call a function from the other frame, to update the captcha. But you did not load the whole frameset - and therefor the function is not reachable in the expected way.

And for getting the result you have to get the content of the other frame.

This code seems to work:

```
    // work with the whole frameset
    String url = "http://www.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/jcrS00Alias";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        // do not stop in case of js errors
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage frameset = webClient.getPage(url);
        HtmlPage searchPage = (HtmlPage) frameset.getFrameByName("leftFrame").getEnclosedPage();

        HtmlForm htmlForm = searchPage.getElementByName("mainForm");

        // set search field
        HtmlTextInput input1 = htmlForm.getInputByName("search1");
        input1.setText("10468790497");

        // process captcha
        HtmlImage image = searchPage.<HtmlImage>getFirstByXPath("//img[@src='captcha?accion=image']");
        ImageReader img = image.getImageReader();
        BufferedImage buf = img.read(0);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buf);
        String codigo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, icon, "Captcha image", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        HtmlTextInput input2 = htmlForm.getInputByName("codigo");
        input2.setText(codigo);

        // click the button
        HtmlElement boton = htmlForm.getElementsByAttribute("input", "value", "Buscar").get(0);
        boton.click();

        // and get the result
        HtmlPage resultPage = (HtmlPage) frameset.getFrameByName("mainFrame").getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println(resultPage.asText());
    }
```

But you need the latest HtmlUnit snapshot to run this without an js error (there was a strange bug introduced 10 years ago) that is now fixed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you; Another possible solution: https://youtu.be/wJYNrmiE4lY